# Getting 2 user inputs within the same MIPS code

Tags: assembly, mips

I am trying to get input for 2 "variables" a and b. There are 2 strings (prompt1 and prompt2) which display a message to store the variables. When I run the code, executing prompt1 prints out both statements however, when I execute prompt2 it only prints out the prompt2 statements (I want it to do what prompt2 does).

```
    .data 
prompt1: .ascii "\nPlease enter input for a: "
    
prompt2: .ascii "\nPlease enter input for b: "

main:
.text


    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt1 
    syscall 

    li $v0, 5
    syscall

    move $t0, $v0
    
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt2
    syscall 

    li $v0, 5
    syscall

    move $t1, $v0
```

This is the output.
[image: Code Output]

Comment: You need to null terminate the strings so that the syscall knows where to stop.  You can use `.asciiz` instead of `.ascii`, or, explicitly put a zero at the end of each string, by using a `.byte 0` declaration.